# Change string of application externally c#

Tags: c#, windows, reverse-engineering, portable-executable

I have a client application that connects to my server

I do not have access to the client's code anymore so how would I be able to change the string `192.168.2.12` into another string in order for me to be able to make it connect to my own server. In what way would I be able to do this in C# programmatically?

Thanks.

[image: IMG]

Comment: Is the client application a .NET executable?

Comment: It's not in a configuration file?

Comment: You will need to reverse engineer the client application to figure out where it gets the address from. Hopefully it gets it from a configuration file or something else that you can change.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No its a win32 PE executable

Comment: @HansKeﬆing No , its stored inside the executable

Comment: Want to modify a string value embedded in a binary (exe) file by modifying the bytes content? In this case, you have to use a [Hex File Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor) or create your own module in your app... but this does not guarantee the result due to offsets and encodings. Therefore you need to use a [Resource File Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_(Windows)). Is that it? If not, you have to improve the question, please.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Yes exactly, by changing the bytes, but I did mention in the question that i want to change the value of the string in  the exectuable programmatically.

Comment: @pillpopper228 So that's too broad because you are asking how to make a full hex file editor or a full resource file editor that modifies a third party binary file exe/dll. Such things can be free and/or open-source as well as commercial and it requires many time to do that... Feel free to open any question to solve a programming, algorithm or model problem with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to decompile the program and then search in the original source code how the value is set and adjust accordingly.

Comment: if my memory serves me right, it was literally set like this, const char* IP = "192.168.2.12" into connect()

Comment: If it's a constant there is no way you can manipulate it from outside of the program (e.g. config). If you're lucky you can decompile the original program, and then adjust in the source code the constant value to what you want it to be. Once adjusted, build locally and see if it works.

Comment: What if the value was stored in a char array then? I'll try to reproduce the strings in another native c++ app and see if i can change them

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the configuration strings are written in .exe.config
Just look at the client folder location to see if you have any files ending with .exe.config. There might be the string in it and you can change it there.